# Analytic continuation of Riemann Theta function to positive semidefinite matrices

Tags: special-functions, analytic-continuation, theta-functions

The Riemann $\Theta$-function is defined as 
$$Θ(z|Ω)=\sum\limits_{q∈Z^N}e^{πiq⋅Ωq+2πiq⋅z},$$
where $\Omega$ has positive definite imaginary part to ensure convergence. In a particle physics calculation I encountered this series, except $\Omega$ is purely imaginary and positive semi-definite. In particular I have $N=2k$, and $q\cdot\Omega q=0$, iff $q=(v,v)$ with $v\in Z^k$.

Clearly $\Theta(z\vert\Omega)$ does not converge in this case, so my question is: Is it possible to analytically continue $\Theta(z\vert \Omega)$ to $\Omega$'s with positive semidefinite imaginary parts? Or if this is too hard: Does anyone have an idea about analytically continuing the particular case above?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the simplest possible nontrivial case? With $k=1$ what do you get?

Comment: With the concrete $\Omega$ matrix that appears in my problem the $k=1$ can be written as $$\Theta(0\vert\Omega)=\sum_{v,w\in\mathbb{Z}} e^{-c(v-w)^2},$$
where c is a positive constant. I chose $z=0$ as it is the most relevant case to me (or equivalently $z\in\mathbb{Z}$). You can clearly see the divergence coming from the diagonal elements in this case.